# java code that shows file type

Tags: java

the code that shows file type in dir give the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: Io.File
    at Io.DirectoryHtmlFiles.main(DirectoryHtmlFiles.java:9)
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)"   `
```

There is the code: the code is for package Io

```
package Io;
import java.io.*;

class DirectoryHtmlFiles { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        String dirname = "D:\\"; 
        File f1 = new File(dirname); 
        FilenameFilter only = new OnlyExt("html"); 
        String s[] = f1.list(only); 
        for (int i=0; i < s.length; i++) { 
            System.out.println(s[i]); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You ignored an error message issued by the compiler, and then tried to run the resulting `.class` file, which is not runnable.  This is probably because you appear to have your own class `Io.File` that is conflicting with `java.io.File`.  It is very bad practice to name your own classes the same a JRE/JDK classes, even if they are in different packages.  Since you have not posted the complete source file I'm not 100% sure this answer is complete so I'm posting it as a comment until you clarify. Please [edit] your question and include all of the source file.

Comment: Any IDE would immediately display compilation errors here! So why not use an IDE?

Comment: the package name is package Io;

Comment: That's obvious.  Until you add the complete source code the question is unanswerable and therefore off-topic.

Comment: added file to another package still same error, the source code is shown above

Comment: the ide is netbeans

Comment: Your filter is not working and there is no way of knowing why unless you show the **OnlyExt** class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package javas;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class DirectoryHtmlFiles {

public static void main(String a[]){
            int Count = 0;
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaWeb");
    String[] files = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html")){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    for(String f:files){
                    Count++;
        System.out.println(f);
                    System.out.println(Count);
    }
}
```

figured it another way the above code produces the result
JsCounts.html
1
JsForm.html
2
which is the file type with count, thanks

Comment: Just a heads up but this is higly illogical to my eyes:

 if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html")){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

why not just return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html");

Comment: required was a program that lists file name and count, does the job thanks for comment anyway

Comment: It's Minor but I  agree with @Aris, the **if/else** within the **accept** method is not required in this case since `return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".html");` will do the same thing with a **lot** less clutter.